# Facebook Graph api, read messages send to a page with page access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a Graph API web hook that litens for conversations on a page.
I get a ping on my web-hook when I send message to the associated page with this body.

```
{"entry":[
  {"changes":
   [
    {
     "field":"conversations",
     "value":{
       "thread_id":"t_mid.$cAASnBD_EQdhjNJRBZVdA0750e5Q_",
       "page_id":<page-id>,
       "thread_key":"t_100018072547807"
      }
    }
   ],
   "id":"<page-id",
   "time":1499003405
  }
],
"object":"page"}
```

I used the thread-id mentioned in the post to get the messages in the thread with the url

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/t_mid.$cAASnBD_EQdhjNJRBZVdA0750e5Q_/messages?access_token=<page_access_token>
```

This is the response I got for this

```
    {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAASnBD_EQdhjNJVyd1dA1AqR4yFf",
            "created_time": "2017-07-02T12:39:31+0000"
        },
        ...
    ],
    "paging": {
        "cursors": {
            "before": "some-big-text",
            "after": "some-big-text"
        }
    }
}
```

So, I take one message from the data array, with thread_id `"m_mid.$cAASnBD_EQdhjNJVyd1dA1AqR4yFf"`

and make the following request, `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/m_mid.$cAASnBD_EQdhjNNYLBldA5DEDHRgj?access_token=<page-access-token>`, hoping that I'll be able to read the message.

But the response is just

```
{
   "id": "m_mid.$cAASnBD_EQdhjNNYLBldA5DEDHRgj",
   "created_time": "2017-07-02T13:50:05+0000"
}
```

and has no message text in the body.

The following permissions were requested from user

```
public_profile, manage_pages, publish_pages, read_page_mailboxes, pages_messaging
```

What am I missing? how can I read the messages send by a user with the message Id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request to fetch the messages of that conversations looks okay, but you have to add the fields you like to get to the request, too.

So the request should like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/t_mid.$cAASnBD_EQdhjNJRBZVdA0750e5Q_/messages?fields=id,message,from,to&access_token=<page_access_token>
```

Comment: Could you post the documentation link. I couldn't find this at all!!

Comment: Documentation of the message fields: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/message/

Documentation of the fields in general: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api